# Groovy access multiple member variable

Tags: groovy

Is there any convention like this in `groovy` to access member variables

```
class Emp {
   String name
   String name1
}

Emp emp = new Emp()
emp {
  name = "name"
  name1 = "name1"
}
```

rather than repeating the object again and again

```
emp.name = "name"
emp.name1 = "name1"
```

Somewhere I have seen a convention like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*with*](http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_using_with_for_repeated_operations_on_the_same_bean):

```
class Emp {
   String name
   String name1
}

Emp emp = new Emp()
emp.with {
  name = 'name'  // -> emp.name = 'name'
  name1 = 'name1'  // -> emp.name1 = 'name1'
}

assert emp.name == 'name'
assert emp.name1 == 'name1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Emp emp = new Emp(name: "name", name1: "name1")
```

See http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_initializing_beans_with_named_parameters_and_the_default_constructor